# How to validate Selectize.js tags with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am able to implemented [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) tags by using jQuery. But I want to validate the required field in a validator. So, how to validate the required field of Selectize.js tags.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you using [JQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for validation?

Comment: yes, I have implemented jquery.validate.js file in my project

Answer (score 2):

By using [JQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) you can validate your [Selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) tags like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="mySelect" placeholder="Select a person..." required>
        <option value="">Select a person...</option>
        <option value="1">Chuck Testa</option>
        <option value="4">Sage Cattabriga-Alosa</option>
        <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button id="btnTestForm">Test Form</button>
```

**JQuery/Javascript:**

```
$('#mySelect').selectize();

$("#myForm").validate({
    ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input'
});

$("#btnTestForm").click(function(e) {
    if($("#myForm").valid())
        alert("form is valid"); 
    else
        alert('form is NOT valid');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/249Wz/4/

Comment: Please applied tags when you use selectize.js and try to apply validation then what you find please let me know because your suggestion I already applied in my project but still it is not working in tags condition of selectize.js.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you add your source code, so I can check into it what you already have done with?

Comment: Ok I will add my code and please test it from your side.

Comment: var sportArray=[];
sportArray=[{'value':1,'label':'sport1'},{'value':2,'label':'sport2'}];

//Initialize the selectize.js
$('select#ddlSport')[0].selectize;

   $('select#ddlSport').selectize({

                    plugins: ['remove_button'],
                    maxItems: null,
                    valueField: 'value',
                    labelField: 'label',
                    searchField: 'label',
                    options: sportArray,
                    create: false

                });

Please let me your feedback when u trying to validate this field.